# Как выгрузить файл, имя которого на русском языке

Tags: c#, .net

Имеется такой код:

```
[SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "Test" })]
[HttpGet("test")]
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> Test([FromQuery] string param)
    {
        var result = await _test.Test2(param);

        Response.Headers[HeaderNames.AccessControlExposeHeaders] = "content-disposition";
        return new(result, "application/octet-stream")
        {
            FileDownloadName = "Русский язык.xls"
        };
    }
```

Проблема в том, что на фронт прилетает файл без русских букв в названии. Как это можно исправить?